# crawled (200) but didn't get scraped - Crawlera

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy, web-crawler

Hi again I'm on the C10 plan and trying to scrape amazon website;

I'm having this issue that sometimes log says a website is crawled but then it won't scrape the data I wanted and it jumps on the the next page as I instructed. from some pages it would scrape from some it won't I don't understand. Like I checked the code and the html of the url and there are items to be scraped on the sites that it says crawled but didn't scrape. Can anyone help me understand whats' going on? I was thinking that maybe the website returning a captcha but even then I thought crawlera automatically retries the requests that it gets captcha for.

Below is the log:

```
'time': '2017-02-12',
'title': u'Basic GIS Coordinates, Second Edition',
'url': u'https://www.amazon.com/Basic-GIS-Coordinates-Second-Sickle/dp/1420092316/ref=sr_1_64?s=tradein-aps&srs=9187220011&ie=UTF8&qid=1486932384&sr=1-64'}
2017-02-12 14:46:31 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/s//s/ref=sr_nr_n_3/153-6246827-9833634?srs=9187220011&fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A283155%2Cn%3A%211000%2Cn%3A173507%2Cn%3A173515%2Cn%3A227541%2Cn%3A13735&bbn=227541&ie=UTF8&qid=1486860051&rnid=227541> (referer: None)
2017-02-12 14:46:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/s//s/ref=sr_nr_n_2/153-6246827-9833634?srs=9187220011&fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A283155%2Cn%3A%211000%2Cn%3A173507%2Cn%3A173515%2Cn%3A227541%2Cn%3A52187011&bbn=227541&ie=UTF8&qid=1486860051&rnid=227541> (referer: None)
2017-02-12 14:46:44 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_2/153-6246827-9833634?bbn=227541&fst=as%3Aoff&ie=UTF8&page=2&qid=1486932385&rh=n%3A283155%2Cn%3A%211000%2Cn%3A173507%2Cn%3A173515%2Cn%3A227541%2Cn%3A13735&srs=9187220011> (referer: https://www.amazon.com/s//s/ref=sr_nr_n_3/153-6246827-9833634?srs=9187220011&fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A283155%2Cn%3A%211000%2Cn%3A173507%2Cn%3A173515%2Cn%3A227541%2Cn%3A13735&bbn=227541&ie=UTF8&qid=1486860051&rnid=227541)
2017-02-12 14:46:44 [scrapy.log] DEBUG: successfully added!
2017-02-12 14:46:44 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_2/153-6246827-9833634?bbn=227541&fst=as%3Aoff&ie=UTF8&page=2&qid=1486932385&rh=n%3A283155%2Cn%3A%211000%2Cn%3A173507%2Cn%3A173515%2Cn%3A227541%2Cn%3A13735&srs=9187220011>
{'currency': u'$',
```

Comment: as you have a crawlera plan, I would suggest asking direct assistance in [their support page](https://support.scrapinghub.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are crawling amazon, my guess would be that you are getting a "captcha" page instead of a regular product page.

Maybe you should print the content of your response instead of just returning items, then you'll be sure about what page is exactly crawled.

Comment: Yeah I had other post about the same issue and someone suggested that it could be a captcha problem so i tried using crawlera since they deal with that, but i still obtain the same behaviour. Thanks for the suggestion im gonna go ahead and print a content like you suggested to understand what's going on. Altough what whould be common for every page? like what should i try to print?

Comment: Try response.body or something alike, get it human readable if it's not

Comment: isnt response.body return the whole html script? in that case i'd be printing a lot and won't be able to see much I mean it'd be crowded. What do you mean by saying get it human readable? how can i do that?

Comment: yes it does return a whole html. then, just print reponse.url, by the way if you are basing your question on the log you are seeing, it is not relevant, scraping is quite quick and not everything makes it to the output

Comment: I checked the database and I don't have the items that I suppose to have from that url. Can there be an issue like crawling too fast so that the pipeline gets stucked or something like i use mongodb, i put the items scraped to the database in mongodb. Maybe it crawls too fast and mongodb can't keep up and only put some of the items in? could that be a thing?